# SQLite3::open using PHP selecting all rows?

Tags: php, sqlite

How can I select all rows using SQLite3::open? The following code only outputs one row.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Simple example of extending the SQLite3 class and changing the __construct
     * parameters, then using the open method to initialize the DB.
     */

    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('db_backups/database_123456789.db');
        }
    }

    $db = new MyDB();

    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM myBookmarks');
    var_dump($result->fetchArray());
    // ONLY DUMPS ONE RESULT
    ?>
```

I got my starting code here.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php

Comment: This is usually the case for all db result handlers.  Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-array-query.php

Comment: Also, the query isn't run from `open` method. It's run from the `query` method. Maybe you need to read all of the documentation to get a better understanding before trying to implement code you don't understand.

Comment: I get an error when I try this code: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()

Comment: I found the answer. I posted it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Soooo, reading the documentation further helped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) 
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

It can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php